# signature for a RESTFUL update in Rails for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I'm converting some update code from a hand-coded to a standard restful route but am having some problems

My route is:

```
resources :items, only: [:create, :update], :controller => "api_items"
```

and my spec is:

```
describe 'task030: updating header / detail of a Item', task030: true do
  it 'should update the header detail of a MenuItem' do
    item=FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    # not working
    #put :update,  { header: "my menu item header MELISSA BALDWIN", detail: "my menu item yadda yadda", global_id: menu_item.global_id, position: 1 }
    put :update, id: item.id, item: { header: "my menu item header MELISSA BALDWIN", detail: "my menu item yadda yadda", global_id: menu_item.global_id, position: 1 }
```

The error I get is about an intermediary item but I think my put is just wrong? Any help in diagnosing what's off?

thx in advance

Comment: I'd say... stick with the naming conventions of rails, and save yourself the issues. `resources :api_items, path: :items, only: [:create, :update]`. Now you call api_items everywhere, but the url shows 'items'. Might save yourself some headache with that.

Comment: that's actually what I'm trying to do. We had a bunch of custom paths that I'm trying to migrate to Raisl resources. The :updates are giving me a problem though. :destroy and :create are fine. It looks like as least in 3.2.13 that I need to wrap the second and third args into a single hash.

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting? Also, can you confirm that you've established the controller as the subject of the test in some higher level context?